# JPA (Hibernate) pack multiple enum values into a single byte array using stored function

Tags: hibernate, jpa, enums, oracle11g

I am currently trying to map a legacy database schema (which I cannot easily alter) into **JPA 1.0** (provider is Hibernate 3.3). The schema was designed in the days when disk space was at a premium, so there are several cases where multiple distinct values are packed into binary byte arrays. For example, given the following three enums:

```
enum ItemA { A, B, C }
enum ItemB { E, F }
enum ItemC { G, H, I, J }
```

These will be compressed into a **single bit-string column** where:

- the first 2 bits encode `ItemA` (`A = 0b01`, `B = 0b10`, `C = 0b11`),
- the next bit is `ItemB` (`0 = E`, `1 = F`); and
- the next 2 bits are `ItemC` (`G = 0b00`, `H = 0b01`, `I = 0b10`, and `J = 0b11`).

So, in order to map this I would need to mask off the range of bits for each `enum` and then map that to the corresponding values.

To make matters worse, the actual bit positions and masks used for each `enum` and each value in that `enum` vary depending on some other config tables stored in the database. The only supported way of packing and unpacking these values is via a set of **stored functions (PL/SQL)**:

```
function pack_data(item_a in char(1), item_b in char(1), item_c in char(1)) returns raw...
function unpack_data_item_a(bit_string in raw) returns char(1) ..
function unpack_data_item_b(bit_string in raw) returns char(1) ..
etc
```

My current JPA mapping for this looks like the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_table")
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "entity_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "bit_string")
    private byte[] bitstring;

    @Transient
    private ItemA itemA;
    @Transient
    private ItemB itemB;
    @Transient
    private ItemC itemC;
    ...
}
```

The question is: **How can I go about automatically populating (unpacking) these `enum` fields on load, and then automatically packing them into the bitstring again on insert/update?** If they were read-only then I'd just hide them in a view and map them as read-only.

**Possible solutions discussion:**

I thought about using `@PrePersist`/`@PreUpdate` lifecycle callbacks, but the Hibernate docs say not to touch the `EntityManager` in these callbacks, which makes it somewhat difficult to access the database. I could add a new persistence unit and use a `REQUIRES_NEW` transaction to access the stored procedures in the lifecycle callbacks, perhaps? That seems a little hacky.

Could Hibernate specific `@SqlUpdate`/`@SqlInsert` annotations to override the SQL be the solution? It seems possible, but I'm scared off by the need to rely on the (somewhat arbitrary looking) order that Hibernate expects the bind variables to appear - is this stable over time?

**Edit:** Another possibility is to use the view for read and use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger to populate the bit-string. I'd like to avoid that if possible as it is hidden from JPA and might confuse other devs.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: This question seems to have been edited without my knowledge or consent. Is that usual behaviour on SO? I'm not keen on the result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After investigating the custom Hibernate type option suggested by IsNull, I decided that for this particular case it was rather too much code - and raw JDBC code too (inside the custom type). Instead I opted to make the MyEntity class effectively immutable, and to add a MyEntityBuilder (builder pattern) to create it. The builder collects the various enum fields and then calculates the packed bit string in the final build() step:

```
public class MyEntityBuilder {
    private final EntityManager em;
    private ItemA a;
    ...

    public MyEntityBuilder(final EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }
    public MyEntityBuilder setA(ItemA a) {
        this.a = a;
        return this;
    }
    // other setters...
    public MyEntity build() {
        final byte[] packedData = (byte[])
              em.createNamedQuery(MyEntity.PACK_DATA)
                .setParameter("item_a", a)
                .setParameter("item_b", b)
                .setParameter("item_c", c)
                .getSingleResult();
        return new MyEntity(packedData, a, b, c);
    }
}
```

Where MyEntity.PACK_DATA is a named native query that calls the stored function and returns the packed binary data. This takes care of writing the data, as the builder ensures that the packed bit_string is correct on construction. For reading, I use the original wrapper view and mark the enum fields as insertable=false, updateable=false (although I might move to Hibernate @Formula annotations here).

Compared to the custom Hibernate type approach, the builder pattern is both shorter code (as we can use JPA itself to do the queries rather than writing JDBC code), and avoids any Hibernate-specific code at all. Callers do need to be aware to use the Builder and need access to an EntityManager, but that's usually not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

When your database columns do not 1:1 map to your entity logic, this usually means that you should use a custom type (hibernate user type) to map the data. You can then do all your logic in this user type and your entity can stay clean.

You implement a org.hibernate.usertype.UserType - resulting in your **SuperEnumUserType**.
In your entity, you annotate the enum property with @Type:

```
@Type(type = "my.cool.project.SuperEnumUserType")
private ItemA itemA;
```

See here for an example: http://javadata.blogspot.de/2011/07/hibernate-and-user-types.html

Comment: Thanks. Can you point me at an example? The examples in the Hibernate docs seem to assume that I can just bind the fields as parameters to a PreparedStatement. Should I call getConnection() on that to make my stored function calls and then bind the result into the statement?

Comment: I've added some more detail, and added a link to a tutorial which shows how you can map a single column to multiple properties.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I spent some time investigating the custom Hibernate type approach, but it ended up being too much code for too little benefit. I've added another answer detailing the approach that worked for me in the end.